# How to bind form inputs to dictionary values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm creating an ASP.NET core razor page web app, one of the pages need to be able to modify a `Dictionary<string, string>` property.

The object i am trying to modify is as follows:

```
public class Element
{
    [Key]
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
}
```

I am able to dispay the values on the page using the following code:

```
<form method="POST">
    <ul>
        <li hidden="true">ID: <input asp-for="FocusedItem.ID"/></li>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FocusedItem.Values.Count(); i++)
        {
            <li>@Model.FocusedItem.Values.ElementAt(i).Key: <input asp-for="@Model.FocusedItem.Values.ElementAt(i).Value"/></li>
        }
    </ul>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The pagemodel cointains the following method to handle post events:

```
public void OnPost(Element FocusedItem)
{
}
```

The "ID" property is populated properly, however, the "Values" property has a count of 0 (the input values on the form are not binding to the Dictionaty). How can this be resplved?

Also bonus question - how can one add a new element to the dictionary?

Edit: Code -
-cshtml: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thezaza101/RDMUI/master/Pages/Data/ElementManager.cshtml
-cs: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thezaza101/RDMUI/master/Pages/Data/ElementManager.cshtml.cs

Comment: What is your view strongly typed to ? How and where are you populating the `Values`  property ?

Comment: @shyju What do you mean by what my view is strongly type to? This app is a UI to a REST service, I have a "FocusedItem" property in my PageModel of type Element which is populated by the server in the OnGet() method.

Comment: Try using a pair of fields like `<input name="Values[0][key]">` & `<input name="Values[0][value]">`.

Comment: @MarkG No luck with that method unfortunatly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@MarkG was close, but the actual syntax would be: `Values[N].Key` and `Values[N].Value`, where `N` is your index. However, since you're using tag helpers to generate the fields, the true problem is your use of `ElementAt`. Model expressions cannot include arbitrary methods, as there's no way to bind to something like `ElementAt` in the resultant POST handling. Instead, you must use the indexing syntax, i.e. `[i]`. However, there's where using a dictionary breaks down, as it can't be indexed by item position - only key.

Honestly, I tend to avoid posting dictionaries, as it's unstructured data. 99.99% of the time you'd probably be better served by breaking that off into a class with properties instead of a dictionary of keys. If you insist on using a dictionary, you can *try* passing the actual key values as indexers:

```
@foreach (var key in Model.Values.Keys)
{
    <input asp-for="Values[key]" />
}
```

I haven't tried that personally, but I think it should work. Short of that, the only way I *know* works is generating the input names manually:

```
<input name="Values[@i].Key" value="@Model.Values.ElementAt(i).Key" />
<input name="Values[@i].Value" value="@Model.Values.ElementAt(i).Value" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to make some changes to my PageModel however your first suggestion worked. It seems that it will bind to a "Dictionary<string, string> Values" if its a property of the PageModel however it will not bind to a sub property (FocusedItem.Values). Also the reason i needed to use ElementAt() is becouse the key of the dictionary is a string - Values[@i] gives me an error.